# How to set background color to transparent?

Tags: html, css, transparent

I want to set the `background-color` of my header to transparent, but when I use `background-color: transparent` nothing happens.

When I use `background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5)`, I get `(255,127,127)` in every browser.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chPbw.jpg)

How can I set the `background-color` to transparent?

Okay I think this could help:

In the Html its:

```
<!-- Header -->
        <div id="header" class="alt">
        <h1 id="logo">Christina Stephan</a></h1>
            <p>Schauspielerin - Sängerin - Sprecherin</p>
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
                    <li><a href="vita.html">Vita</a></li>
                    <li><a href="fotos.html">Fotos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="medien.html">Medien</a></li>
                    <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

So the CSS is:

```
#header {
    background: #fff
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0.0375em 0.125em 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    height: 3.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.11em;
    line-height: 4.6em;
    position: fixed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: try background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)

Comment: fully transparent or just slightly faded?

Comment: Hey, I would like to do it fully transparent OR if its better looking slightly faded (depends on what my girlfriend wants, it's her website)

Comment: Now i did:  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) what sagar kodte suggested, but now its grey (153,153,153) or #999999

Comment: `rgba(0,0,0,0,0)`  the last number is transparency. Using "0.5" or 0.4" is 50/40% opacity, not transparent.

Comment: *How* does `background-color: transparent;` not work? That's how you make a background transparent in CSS.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you can tell me? I am at one's wits' end!

Comment: When I do `background-color: transparent;` its just white

Answer (score 3):

You can to [the `opacity` property:](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

```
.transparent {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

You can also do it with the property `background-color` and the [`rgba()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp). The last parameter represents the opacity, setting it to `0` will set the color to be transparent.

Comment: I did that but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

you can use opacity to make color transparent .. 
set proper color first then do this

```
 {opacity:0}
```

Comment: I did and nothing changed

Comment: give it less than 1 like `opacity:0.2`

Comment: first set some background color than give this property.

Answer (score 1):

use this (CSS) :

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Comment: it is because there is nothing behind it: If there is a background image you can see the transparency.